# Is there a way to get Yslow to work with Silverlight or Lightswitch?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch, yslow

I have tryed to run Yslow on a LS/SL application and everytime I run it the yslow application hangs and does not process. Is there anything I can do to make yslow work on SL/LS app?

Comment: could you please share a link so I can reproduce the error? Which browser are you testing from? FF, Chrome? Thanks!

Comment: Its FF. Unfortunately I can not send out a URL for this because its local in my environment. Does this mean it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following:

- [ySlow bookmarklet](https://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/mobile/)
- [xPerf](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/21/measuring-browser-performance-with-the-windows-performance-tools.aspx#10034329)